# Oracle Database SQL - Embedded selects

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am attempting to build a script to retrieve a list of "edit_mnemonic" values that are populated for today. To do this, I have to check against the "last_analysis_date" on the claim table.

I am working with three tables

**claim              - primary key "claim_iid" - contains last_analysis_date, claim_EID**

**claim_line         - primary key "claim_line_iid" - contains "claim_iid"**

**claim_line_edits   - primary key "claime_line_edit_iid" - contains "claim_line_iid", "edit_mnemonic"**

So far I have come up with

```
select edit_mnemonic

from claim_line_edit

where claim_line_iid in 
(select claim_line_iid from claim_line where claim_iid in 

(select claim_iid from claim where to_date(last_analysis_date) >= to_date(sysdate)));

select claim_eid from claim where to_date(last_analysis_date) >= to_date(sysdate);
```

This gives me the following:

```
EDIT_MNEMONIC       
--------------------
MFD                 
ICM                 
EST                 
ICM                 
EST                 

5 rows selected.

CLAIM_EID                                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1850735 B                                                                       
9999999                                                                         
9999999                                                                         

3 rows selected.
```

My question is, how can I select the corresponding claim_EID from the claim table for these edit_mnemonics, within the same statement? Do I need to use a join here?

I tried using

```
select edit_mnemonic, claim_eid

from claim_line_edit, claim

where claim_line_iid in 
(select claim_line_iid from claim_line where claim_iid in 

(select claim_iid from claim where to_date(last_analysis_date) >= to_date(sysdate)));
```

The result was that I received a list of ALL claim_eid's on the claim table.

My desired output would be

```
EDIT_MNEMONIC      CLAIM_EID       
-------------      ---------
MFD                1850735 B 
ICM                9999999 
EST                9999999 
ICM                9999999 
EST                9999999 

5 rows selected.
```

Thank you for your time in reading my post, please let me know if additional information is needed.

Comment: Why are you using a subery here at all, rather than just joining? Also `to_date(sysdate)` is wrong - what is that supposed to achieve?

Comment: Hi Alex. I suppose the only answer to your initial question would be that I am not approaching the script appropriately. Also this is the first time that I have used sysdate in a script, I added the to_date to ensure that the data types matched. I can remove it. Did you have any constructive advice perhaps?

Comment: It was supposed to be constructive, or at least establish a baseline for what you're trying to do. SYSDATE is already a date, so `to_date()` does implict conversions and relies on NLS settings. Knowing *why* you were doing that would indicate if you should use the raw value or were trying to truncate it back to midnight, i.e. get all claims last analysed today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select edit_mnemonic, claim_eid
from claim_line_edits cle join claim_line cl on cle.claim_line_iid = cl.claim_line_iid 
                          join claims c on cl.claim_iid = c.claim_iid
where last_analysis_date >= trunc(sysdate)
```

This assumes last_analysis_date is in date format, as it should be; otherwise you would need your to_date(last_analysis_date), better yet with an explicit date format.

Comment: Thank you for looking at my question Mathguy. Unfortunately I cannot join claim to claim_line_edit because claim_line_edit does not contain claim_iid. Claim_iid is only found in claim, and claim_line. Claim_line contains the claim_line_iid which then correlates to the claim_line_edits table. So I believe I would need to join claim -> claim_line -> claim_line_edit . That is the piece that is really confusing me. Thank you again.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the structure of your tables. This can still be done with a join, you just need to join all three tables. I also noted an inconsistency between claim_line_edit or claim_line_edits, use whichever name is correct for your table. Fixing the query in the Answer in a minute.

Comment: Unless there are analysis dates in the future, I *suspect* the OP wants to compare with `trunc(sysdate)`.

Comment: Sick. That's what I meant to write, got interrupted by a phone call right in the middle...   Will fix.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help!!! I promise I am trying to learn as I go :) Thank you.

Comment: I am only a few steps ahead of you, you can probably even see me.  :-)